# recursive function output weird values

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

im trying to complete a kata in codewars using JavaScript, these are the instructions:

```
The Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following integer sequence (Fn):

    0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, ...
    such as

    F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) with F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1.
    Given a number, say prod (for product), we search 
    two Fibonacci numbers F(n) and F(n+1) verifying

    F(n) * F(n+1) = prod.
    Your function productFib takes an integer (prod) and returns an array:

    [F(n), F(n+1), true] or {F(n), F(n+1), 1} or (F(n), F(n+1), True)
    depending on the language if F(n) * F(n+1) = prod.

    If you don't find two consecutive F(m) verifying F(m) * F(m+1) = prod
    you will return

    [F(m), F(m+1), false] or {F(n), F(n+1), 0} or (F(n), F(n+1), False)
    F(m) being the smallest one such as F(m) * F(m+1) > prod.

    Examples

    productFib(714) # should return [21, 34, true], 
                    # since F(8) = 21, F(9) = 34 and 714 = 21 * 34

    productFib(800) # should return [34, 55, false], 
                    # since F(8) = 21, F(9) = 34, F(10) = 55 and 21 * 3
```

well, i just need to create a fibonacci series and return array, here is my code:

```
function productFib(prod) {
    return fib(0, 1, prod);
}
function fib(a, b, prod) {
    if (a * b < prod) {
        return (a + b) + fib(b, a + b, prod);
    }
    else if (a * b == prod) {
        return [a, b, true];
    }
    else {
        return [a, b, false];
    }
}
```

it is a recursive fibonacci series, how ever, when i run it i dont get the expected array, the result is right, the variables have the correct value and all, but when returning the array i get a very long first element, it looks like it contains the whole fibonacci serie. 
Here is a test case: `(productFib(4895), [55, 89, true])`

if i run my code with that test i get the following:

```
productFib(4895)
"12358132134558955,89,true"
```

can you guys explain me what is going on there?

Comment: `fib()` sometimes returns an Array, which ends up as an operand for `+`, which converts it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fib` functon has one case where it returns a single non-array value:

```
return (a + b) + fib(b, a+b, prod);
```

...and two cases where it returns a reference to an array:

```
return [a,b,true];
// and
return [a,b,false];
```

That first one uses the return value in an `+` operation. That coerces the array to a string, which produces a comma-delimited list of its entries converted to strings, and then does string concatenation.

You probably don't want to do string concatenation in that one `return`. Simply changing it to `return fib(b, a + b, prod);` seems to solve the problem:

```js
function productFib(prod) {
  return fib(0, 1, prod);
}

function fib(a, b, prod) {
  if (a * b < prod) {
    return fib(b, a + b, prod);
  } else if (a * b == prod) {
    return [a, b, true];
  } else {
    return [a, b, false];
  }
}
console.log(productFib(4895)); // [55, 89, true]
```

Comment: This will solve the strange output but the code will still be wrong -- he has to "roll back" when he goes over.  His code doesn't do that.  Still I gave +1 because this is the big problem the OP does not understand.

Comment: @Hogan: I've made the post a Community Wiki, if you want to take the answer further... :-) (I guarantee you that you know more about Fibonacci series than I do...)

Comment: Actually I think this is right since I just re-read the requirements and he wants the first one equal to or greater than -- which this does... for some reason I was thinking equal to or less than.

Comment: @Hogan: Easy to do. :-)

Comment: community wiki -- I feel like I have not seen that in 5 years lol.

Comment: Thank you very much!! i thought it may have something to do with return an array sometimes, but didnt think about the concatenation, thanks a lot for the explanation, i see my mistake now.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `(a + b) +` from your return value:

Replace

```
 return (a + b) + fib(b, a+b, prod);
```

with

```
 return fib(b, a+b, prod);
```

Comment: "What" is only so useful without "why."

Comment: I agree, it's not the best answer, I must admin I focused on helping out quickly, since I know how frustrating it is to not spot an error when doing katas.